# No microphone available (Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition)

Tags: sound, dell, microphone, mate, xps

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04--the version preloaded on the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (2015). I've had it for less than a week. I've installed a bunch of software and changed some defaults (I'm running MATE instead of Unity so I'm probably using something close to Ubuntu MATE than stock, without the reinstall).

The microphone input was working for awhile. I used it to make several video calls over Skype and Google Hangouts. The last time I tried making a video call, however, I discovered that no audio input device was detected. I've tried everything I know and the system seems to believe the microphone doesn't exist. I could likely get it to work again if I just reinstalled the system but I prefer not to lose my settings, so I'd appreciate some direction on how to troubleshoot with the system as-is.

Comment: You likely need to reinstall the drivers.

Comment: The ones included from Dell?

Comment: Could be.  If they have drivers for Ubuntu...

Comment: Are you up to date ? Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and try again...

Comment: Yeah I'm up to date. Ran those just for good measure but there was nothing new to install.

Comment: That weird... Not the best solution but if you absolutely need to use the microphone, install kernel 4.1.7. It will work.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you know that?

Comment: I didn't feel comfortable doing this because jumping to a new major kernel version with an old distribution seems pretty risky. I installed 15.04 instead (I had hesitated but turns out wifi drivers were installed during setup) and the mic works there.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Xfce, when I encounter similar problem I execute `alsactl init` to init the device to make it normal.May be you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Debian and started fiddling with quite a few things until I realised that things were much simpler than expected. I had the following display in pavucontrol:

[image]

I just switched the configuration to Analog Stereo Duplex:

[image]

And then the mic was working properly (no reboot or anything of the sort) and could be configured in the Input Devices:

[image]